# Segmentation fault after trying to delete node from linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

I'm attempting to pass in a linked list, and then delete nodes that aren't numbers. I keep recieving a segmentation fault and I'm not sure where I'm reaching for a pointer that doesn't exist.

```
void clean(node*& start)
    while(start)
        if(*is a number*){
            node* tail = start;
            while (tail->next){
                node* temp = tail->next;
                tail->data = temp->data;
                tail = tail->next;
            }
            if (!tail->next)
                delete tail;
        }
        start= start->next;
    }
}
```

->next is what links the nodes to the rest of the nodes.

Comment: **If** you mean what you say by *"I'm attempting to pass in a linked list, and then delete nodes that aren't numbers"* - I don't see any reason why there should be a `new` in your code; your code is overly complex for your intent

Comment: if `tail->next` is NULL, then the next line is dereferencing null as if it were a node and assigning to a member there

Comment: Alright I've corrected those flaws. Still receiving segmentation fault

Comment: Draw a list of nodes on a piece of paper. Make some nodes numbers and some not numbers, then follow your instructions through the list and watch what happens. When find yourself being instructed to do something silly, change the code so it's not silly. Hint: This `while (tail->next)` seems silly.

Comment: The shown logic appears to be deeply, fundamentally flawed. The stated goal is to "delete nodes that aren't numbers". It logically follows that "if(*is a number*)", then this node belongs in the list, and the process should simply advance to the next node in the list, that's it. Instead of doing that, the code proceeds with executing some confusing loop whose purpose I am unable to decipher. This kind of simple, straightforward task should consist of nothing more than a single pass over the entire list, skipping nodes that do not belong. That's it. No need for any nested loop of some sort.

Comment: Use a debugger and follow your code line by line... or use paper and pencil. There are obvious bugs here like accessing `tail->next` when `tail` is null.  The line `node* temp = new node;` also does not make sense. And more problems!

Comment: In your list creation, do you assign the `next` to be NULL so that you can use that as the end of list delimitation?

Answer (score 0):

This code is all kinds of wrong. The inner loop is completely unnecessary, and updating the `start` pointer on every iteration of the outer loop is fundamentally wrong (the caller would lose their list's `head` pointer every time `clean()` is called).

The code should look something more like this instead:

```
void clean(node* &start)
{
    node *n = start, *prev = NULL, *next;
    while (n)
    {
        next = n->next;
        if (n->data is not a number)
        {
            if (prev) prev->next = next;
            if (start == n) start = next;
            delete n;
        }
        else
            prev = n;
        n = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't leaving the pointer dangle in the `delete n` statement a bit of a set-up for problems later when checking to add or append (erroneously) later?

Comment: @M4rc no. And there is no dangling pointer in this code since other affected nodes are updated before deleting the node

Comment: Just checking my thought process here: If he uses the start variable to repopulate, or insert and it attempts to iterate the list looking for a `null` end, by deleting the pointer the memory is free'd, but the address would still exist, and thus to insert still attempt to dereference to traverse the list. Granted, I'm sure that's implementation dependent. Thoughts?

Comment: @M4rc this code does not delete a null pointer (which is safe to do anyway). And since `start` is passed by reference, the function can update the caller's pointer to point at a new address if it points at a node that is being deleted.